# twitter4j - access tweet information from Streaming API

Tags: twitter4j

What I have so far is taken from code samples on the twitter4j site. It prints out all tweets containing my chosen keywords, as they are provided in real-time by Twitter's Streaming API, but I want to fetch real time tweet?

```
class TweetReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        cb.setDebugEnabled(true);

        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("");
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("");
        cb.setOAuthAccessToken("-");
        cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");

        try {
            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            Twitter twitter1 = tf.getInstance();


        //query based on keyword
            Query query = new Query("HDFC");
            query.count(20);

            //search for tweet
            QueryResult result = twitter1.search(query);

           //make a arraylist to store all tweet

            List<TweetData> tweetList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Status statues : result.getTweets()) {
                TweetData data = new TweetData();
                data.setTweetId("" + statues.getId());
                data.setTweetLanguage(statues.getLang());
                data.setTweetcreatedAt("" + statues.getCreatedAt());
                data.setTweetLocation(statues.getUser().getLocation());
                data.setTweetText(statues.getText());
                data.setFavoriteCount(statues.getFavoriteCount());
                data.setRetweetcount(statues.getRetweetCount());
                data.setInReplyToStatusId(statues.getInReplyToStatusId());
                data.setInReplyToUserId(""+statues.getInReplyToUserId());
                data.setUrlEntities(statues.getURLEntities());
                data.setFollowercount(statues.getUser().getFollowersCount());
                data.setFriendcount(statues.getUser().getFriendsCount());
                data.setUserMentionEntities(statues.getUserMentionEntities());
                data.setHashtagEntities(statues.getHashtagEntities());
                data.setEmail(statues.getUser().getEmail());
                data.setSource(statues.getSource());
                data.setCountrycode(statues.getUser().getWithheldInCountries());

                //insert the tweet into Mongo DB
                Mongodata mongoData = new Mongodata("TEST","127.0.0.1",27017);
                mongoData.add("sma", new Gson().toJson(data));

                //get by key name
                mongoData.getByKey("sma", new Gson().toJson(data));


            //  Map jsonObject = (Map) new Gson().toJson(data);

                //mongoData.getByCondition("sma", jsonObject,"");

                tweetList.add(data);

            }

            // write to DB or write to File, etc using tweetList
            System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(tweetList));

        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }                 
}
```

Comment: " I want to fetch real time tweet" that is the streaming api, what is your question?

Comment: I try to add status listener but it won't work.my question is when execute a code after that some tweet will come.so using status listener how can i fetch that tweet.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the Twitter Search API, if you want to retrieve tweets on real time you need to use the streaming api.
Twitter4j provides examples, and one of them is [exactly what you are looking for](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream/PrintSampleStream.java), however you need to change the line

```
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
```

with

```
     ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
      cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("")
              .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
              .setOAuthAccessToken("")
              .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");

      TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build())
              .getInstance();
```

If you don't, you will have to configure the properties file. After that you will get this code

```
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public final class PrintSampleStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
         ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
          cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("")
                  .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
                  .setOAuthAccessToken("")
                  .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");
          TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build())
                  .getInstance();
        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
                System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
                System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
                System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
                System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        twitterStream.sample();
    }
}
```

With that you'll start to receive the sample public stream. If you want to get specific tweets you will need to use some filters. For example if you want the tweets for an specific query you need to change this line

```
twitterStream.sample();
```

with the word that you want

```
FilterQuery filtre = new FilterQuery();
String[] keywordsArray = { "obama" };
filtre.track(keywordsArray);
twitterStream.filter(filtre);
```

If you want to stream tweets from specifics profiles you will need to use the follow filter. The line `twitterStream.sample();` you will need to change it for this

```
          long[] users = new long[]{someid,someotherid,otherid};
          twitterStream.addListener(listener);
          FilterQuery filtre = new FilterQuery();
          filtre.follow(users);
          twitterStream.filter(filtre);
```

The id's for the array are the id's that Twitter use for every user. If you don't know the id for a certain user you could get it with Twitter4j:

```
User user = tw.showUser("barackobama"); //tw is your Twitter variable from twitter4j.Twitter tw=tf.getInstance();
long id = user.getId();
```

There are more ways to retrieve tweets from the stream, you only need to read the documentation or search on this site. Good luck!